# Compare and insert date and calendar week with two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, mariadb-10.4

I have two tables in my database. In the first table is a column named *date* where i insert a date period in a 1 day interval. In the second table are the *calendar weeks* of the same date period and an autoincrement column *weekid*.

For example I have the *calendar week* 25 with the *weekid* 145 (saved in the second table). The date area is from 21.06-27.06 and is saved in the first table.
Now i want to insert the *weekid* into the first table for every day (*date*) matching the calendar weeks.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `day` (
  `dayid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dayid`)

CREATE TABLE `week` (
  `weekid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `calendar week` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`weekid`
```

Example output for table "day":
weekid: 145
userid: 589
date: 2021-05-06

Example output for table "week":
weekid: 145
userid: 589
calendar week: 25
year: 2021

Does anyone have an idea how to do the date comparison?

Comment: Do this by multiple-table UPDATE query.

Comment: @Akina I edited my question for clarification. My problem is that I dont know how to code the date comparison. For example I have the calendar week 25 with the weekid 145 (saved in the second table). The date area is from 21.06-27.06 and is saved in the first table. Now i want to insert the weekid into the second table matching the datearea

Comment: Provide example data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (3-5 rows per table) and desired output for this data. Also specify your SQL server DBMS and precise version.

Comment: @Akina I cant upload an image of my database :/ I use Mysql. Im really new to database programming so I dont know what you mean by DBMS.

Comment: The data from the image cannot be copied. *I use Mysql.* Provide `SHOW VERSION();` output for precise version. Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` outputs. Provide some data (the values which looks like real ones, hand-made, as formatted table).

Comment: @Akina Server-Typ: MariaDB. Server-Version: 10.4.18-MariaD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the second table you don't have the dates of each week you can just calculate it on the first table right?

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(DOY FROM date_in_table1)/7)
```

should produce the work week of a certain date.

Comment: I have a date area for example 21.06-27.06. And I insert each day of the week in my first table. With this datearea I also insert The calendar week (in this example *25*) in the second table without problems. When inserted into the second table the autoincrement column weekid gives the calendar week an id. I want to insert this Id into the first table matching the week.